# MomentJS - Get date range give a specific day of the month

Tags: javascript, momentjs

Given day of the month of `5` how would you best get the date range between the 5th of last/this month and the next 5th of the month?

```js
// given today is May 24 2021
// should return May 5 - June 5
function getDateRange(selectedDay) {
  const today = moment()
  let previous, next
  if (today.date() >= selectedDay) {
    previous = today.clone().set('date', selectedDay)
    next = today.clone().add(1, 'months').set('date', selectedDay)
  }
  else {
    previous = today.clone().subtract(1, 'months').set('date', selectedDay)
    next = today.clone().set('date', selectedDay)
  }

  return [ previous, next ]
}
```

This works most of the time except for when the selected day doesn't exist for the month (ie. 31st).

For example, if today's date was `Feb 15, 2021` and the `selectedDay` is `31`, the function should return `Jan 31 - Feb 28`.

Does anyone have an elegant solution to this?

Comment: You should try using something other than moment. The creators of moment have said that it is now classed as a legacy project. https://momentjs.com/docs/#/-project-status/. I now use Date-fns https://date-fns.org/

Comment: I am aware of moment's status, however this is a legacy project and already uses momentjs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I edit a bit your code and insert a function to determiante the max date of the month.

```js
// To force a date I inserted a initDate like parameters, remove it if it's unnecessary
function getDateRange(selectedDay, initDate) {
  const today = moment(initDate);

  let previous;
  let next;

  if (today.date() >= selectedDay) {
    previous = moment(today).startOf('month');
    next = moment(today).add(1, 'month').startOf('month');
  } else {
    previous = moment(today).subtract(1, 'months');
    next = moment(today);
  }

  previous = limiter(previous, selectedDay); // this function get the max date of the month
  next = limiter(next, selectedDay);

  return [previous, next];
}

function limiter(dateToLimit, selectedDay) {
  if (moment(dateToLimit).endOf('month').isBefore(moment(dateToLimit).date(selectedDay))) dateToLimit = moment(dateToLimit).endOf('month');
  else dateToLimit = moment(dateToLimit).date(selectedDay);

  return dateToLimit;
}

console.log(getDateRange(31, '2021-02-15'));
console.log(getDateRange(31, '2021-03-15'));
console.log(getDateRange(13, '2021-02-15'));
console.log(getDateRange(13, '2021-09-15'));
console.log(getDateRange(26, '2021-09-15'));
console.log(getDateRange(26, '2021-09-27'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.25.1/moment.min.js"></script>
```